# android : location api asking for wifi

Tags: android, android-location

This is weird. I mean, I have strong network, and GPS is turned On, still it asks for Wifi !!

I'm using new Location Api with class `FusedLocationProviderClient`.

This is how I am checking if Location Settings are enabled or not:

```
private void checkIfLocationSettingsAreEnabled() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationSettingsResponseTask = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
    locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsResponse -> {
        getLastKnownLocation();
    });
    locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            myLocationListener.onResolutionNeeded(e);
        } else {
            myLocationListener.onLocationFailure(e);
        }
    });
}
```

With the above code, I am able to get below image:

[image]

But then, after clicking OK, again I make call to `checkIfSettingsAreEnabled()` this shows another popup as below:

[image]

I wonder why enabling Wifi is mandatory, even if I am on desert safari, where there is no Wifi to connect to !!

Is there any way to **Skip** this `Wifi` option, and work as normal as Google Maps does ?

In fact, Google Maps uses priority `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` and still once, the first settings dialog has been shown, it doesn't ask second time to turn on Wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the below solution, I am able to skip this Wifi Settings Dialog. This is not a perfect solution, but just a workaround till I find perfect solution.

Problem was, even after clicking "Ok" on Settings Dialog, it returned result as `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`. Reason was, Wifi was still turned off. So, as a quick fix, made a check in result `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED`, that if I could get Location by checking `LocationSettingStates`.

You can use my MyLocationUtils.java and Base classes `LocationActivity.java` or `LocationFragment.java`. Happy Coding..!!

for getting location

**MyLocationUtils.java:**

```
public class MyLocationUtils {

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTINGS = 123;

    private static final int INTERVAL_IN_MS = 10000;
    private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MS = 5000;
    private static final int MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS = 5000;
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_UPDATES = 1;

    private final MyLocationListener myLocationListener;
    private final Context context;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

            Location location = null;
            if (locationResult.getLocations().size() > 0) {
                location = locationResult.getLocations().get(0);
            }

            myLocationListener.onLocationSuccess(location);

            stopContinuousLocation();
        }
    };

    public MyLocationUtils(Context context, MyLocationListener myLocationListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.myLocationListener = myLocationListener;

        initializeFusedLocationProviderClient();
    }

    private boolean checkIfRequiredLocationSettingsAreEnabled(Context context) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private void initializeFusedLocationProviderClient() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    }

    public void stopContinuousLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        checkIfLocationSettingsAreEnabled();
    }

    private void checkIfLocationSettingsAreEnabled() {
        if (checkIfRequiredLocationSettingsAreEnabled(context)) {
            getLastKnownLocation();
        } else {
            LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
            builder.addLocationRequest(getLocationRequest());
            builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

            SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);
            Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationSettingsResponseTask = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
            locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnSuccessListener(locationSettingsResponse -> {
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
                // location requests here.
                // ...
                getLastKnownLocation();
            });
            locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
                    myLocationListener.onResolutionNeeded(e);
                } else {
                    myLocationListener.onLocationFailure(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Task<Location> locationTask = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        locationTask.addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
            // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
            if (location != null) {
                myLocationListener.onLocationSuccess(location);
            } else {
                startContinuousLocation();
            }
        });
        locationTask.addOnFailureListener(myLocationListener::onLocationFailure);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void startContinuousLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(getLocationRequest(), mLocationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
                .addOnFailureListener(myLocationListener::onLocationFailure);
    }

    private LocationRequest getLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL_IN_MS);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_MS);
        locationRequest.setNumUpdates(NUMBER_OF_UPDATES);
        locationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MS);
        return locationRequest;
    }

    public void resolveLocationSettings(FragmentActivity fragmentActivity, Exception exception) {
        ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
        try {
            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(fragmentActivity, MyLocationUtils.REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTINGS);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public interface MyLocationListener {

        void onLocationSuccess(Location location);

        void onResolutionNeeded(Exception exception);

        void onLocationFailure(Exception exception);
    }
}
```

**BaseLocationActivity.java:**

```
public abstract class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyLocationUtils myLocationUtils;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myLocationUtils = new MyLocationUtils(this, new MyLocationUtils.MyLocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationSuccess(Location location) {
                if (shouldBeAllowedToProceed())
                    LocationActivity.this.onLocationSuccess(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResolutionNeeded(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                if (shouldBeAllowedToProceed())
                    LocationActivity.this.onResolutionNeeded(exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationFailure(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                if (shouldBeAllowedToProceed())
                    LocationActivity.this.onLocationFailure(exception);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void getLocation() {
        myLocationUtils.getLocation();
    }

    protected void resolveLocationSettings(Exception exception) {
        myLocationUtils.resolveLocationSettings(this, exception);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MyLocationUtils.REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTINGS) {
            final LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    onResolveLocationSettingOk();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to, 
                    // or on Android Oreo 8.1 Wifi Settings were not satisfied inspite of clicking OK, that results on Activity.RESULT_CANCELED
                    onResolveLocationSettingCancelled(locationSettingsStates);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onResolveLocationSettingOk();

    protected void onResolveLocationSettingCancelled(LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates) {
        if (locationSettingsStates.isLocationPresent() && locationSettingsStates.isLocationUsable()) {
            onResolveLocationSettingOk();
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldBeAllowedToProceed() {
        return getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
    }

    public abstract void onLocationSuccess(Location location);

    public abstract void onResolutionNeeded(Exception exception);

    public abstract void onLocationFailure(Exception exception);

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myLocationUtils.stopContinuousLocation();
    }
}
```

**LocationFragment.java:**

```
public abstract class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyLocationUtils myLocationUtils;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myLocationUtils = new MyLocationUtils(context, new MyLocationUtils.MyLocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationSuccess(Location location) {
                if (shouldBeAllowedToProceed())
                    LocationFragment.this.onLocationSuccess(location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResolutionNeeded(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                if (shouldBeAllowedToProceed())
                    LocationFragment.this.onResolutionNeeded(exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationFailure(Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                if (shouldBeAllowedToProceed())
                    LocationFragment.this.onLocationFailure(exception);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void resolveLocationSettings(FragmentActivity appCompatActivity, Exception exception) {
        myLocationUtils.resolveLocationSettings(appCompatActivity, exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MyLocationUtils.REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION_SETTINGS) {
            final LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    onResolveLocationSettingOk();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    onResolveLocationSettingCancelled(locationSettingsStates);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract void onResolveLocationSettingOk();

    protected void onResolveLocationSettingCancelled(LocationSettingsStates locationSettingsStates) {
        if (locationSettingsStates.isLocationPresent() && locationSettingsStates.isLocationUsable()) {
            onResolveLocationSettingOk();
        }
    }

    public void getLocation() {
        myLocationUtils.getLocation();
    }

    private boolean shouldBeAllowedToProceed() {
        return getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
    }

    public abstract void onLocationSuccess(Location location);

    public abstract void onResolutionNeeded(Exception exception);

    public abstract void onLocationFailure(Exception exception);

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myLocationUtils.stopContinuousLocation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`FusedLocationProvider` uses a combo of `GPS` and `WIFI` to get your location.  Especially when asking for balanced mode, it needs both or won't work (`GPS` takes power, so it won't rely just on it for balanced).  Try max accuracy, its less likely to use it then.  Or just use the `GPS` provider if you actually want `GPS`.

Answer (score 0):

> PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY

This priority will go with coarse level accuracy which fetch location only from wi-fi , cellular network or bluetooth and NOT from GPS.

and if device don't have SIM it needs to have wi-fi to get location or it will not call `onLocationChanged` till won't get location.

Comment: So, any way to skip Wifi Settings Dialog option ?